# Native mechanism for parsing input parameter-value pairs from [string]

Tags: parsing, powershell

Is there a native, built-in construct that automatically parses console inputs into variables using the same rules as cmdlet parameters?

For example, many cmdlets accept parameter-value pairs in the form of `-parameter1 unspaced-value1 -parameter2:"spaced value2"`.

I want to read a string using maybe `Read-Host`, and then parse the string into parameter-value pairs and store them into `$variables`, something like `int main(argv, argc)`, but maybe in an associative array or something similar.

Comment: Do you just mean like a hastable? `@{Name="Value"}`

Comment: A hashtable is the main associative array in PowerShell, yes, @Matt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if i understand exactly what you want but you are definitely describing a hashtable which can simply be defined as

```powershell
@{Name="Value";AnotherName="AnotherValue"}
```

Or more readable

```powershell
@{
    Name="Value"
    AnotherName="AnotherValue"
}
```

Both would output the following which could be assigned to a variable which could be used for [splatting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx) (more on that later)

```powershell
Name        Value       
----        -----       
Name        Value       
AnotherName AnotherValue
```

Ok, that's nice but you were looking for a way to use this adhoc with `Read-Host` maybe? This could be where [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849900.aspx) saves the day. In it's simplest form :

```powershell
PS C:\Users\Cameron> $data = "Data=Awesome"

PS C:\Users\Cameron> $data | ConvertFrom-StringData

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                        
----                           -----                                                                                                                                        
Data                           Awesome
```

Ok... that's great.. but what about `Read-Host`. Let's try that now!

```powershell
PS C:\Users\Cameron> Read-Host | ConvertFrom-StringData
Something=Blah

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                        
----                           -----                                                                                                                                        
Something                      Blah
```

This can get complicated if you want to do more than one key/value pair since `Read-Host` doesn't seem to like inserting new lines in the prompt. To cheat I use `-Split` and `-Join`. Split break up the pairs and join ends up creating a newline delimited string which `ConvertFrom-StringData` plays with better. **Side Note** There is a post that has a snippet for creating [multiline input from Read-Host](http://poshcode.org/4471) but this is simpler.

```powershell
PS C:\Users\Cameron> ((Read-Host) -Split ";") -Join "`r`n" | ConvertFrom-StringData
Key1=Value1;Key2=Value2;Key3=Value3  <---- That is what I typed in as a response to Read-Host 

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                        
----                           -----                                                                                                                                        
Key1                           Value1                                                                                                                                       
Key2                           Value2                                                                                                                                       
Key3                           Value3
```

If you are still reading lets use splatting and give an actual reason to use this logic.

```powershell
PS C:\Users\Cameron>  $results = ((Read-Host) -Split ";") -Join "`r`n" | ConvertFrom-StringData
Get-ChildItem @results

Filter=*.txt;Path=C:\\temp    <---- That is what I typed in as a response to `Read-Host`                                                                                                                                    

LastWriteTime : 10/22/2014 11:43:38 PM
Length        : 653018
Name          : out1.txt

....output truncated....
```

**Note:** You should notice in the path I typed in the second backslash `Path=C:\\temp`. The reason comes from the TechNet article for [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849900.aspx)

> `ConvertFrom-StringData` supports escape character sequences that are
>   allowed by conventional machine translation tools. That is, the cmdlet
>   can interpret backslashes (`\`) as escape characters in the string data
>   by using the `Regex.Unescape` Method, instead of the Windows PowerShell
>   backtick character (`` ` ``) that would normally signal the end of a line in
>   a script. Inside the here-string, the backtick character does not
>   work. You can also preserve a literal backslash in your results by
>   **escaping it with a preceding backslash**, like this: `\\`. Unescaped
>   backslash characters, such as those that are commonly used in file
>   paths, can render as illegal escape sequences in your results.

**Small Update**

While the `` ((Read-Host) -Split ";") -Join "`r`n" | ConvertFrom-StringData `` works I'm sure that the following is much simpler.

```powershell
(Read-Host).Replace(";","`r`n") | ConvertFrom-StringData
```