# Error splatting single line string from ConvertFrom-StringData

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

In trying to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630925/native-mechanism-for-parsing-input-parameter-value-pairs-from-string/27631598#27631598) I was trying to show examples of splatting with string data from `Read-Host` which does work to a point.

```
PS C:\temp> $results = (Read-Host) -Split ";" | ConvertFrom-StringData
Get-ChildItem @results

Filter=*.txt;Path="C:\\temp" <--- This was typed in for Read-host
```

The hashtable is created successfully, or so i assumed, however when trying to splat it I get the following error:

```
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'C:\temp\System.Collections.Hashtable' because it does not exist.
At line:2 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem @results
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\temp\System.Collections.Hashtable:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Seems that the issue is im not getting a `hashtable` but a `System.Object[]`

```
$results.GetType().Fullname
System.Object[]
```

Root of my issue is `ConvertFrom-StringData` is not returning a hashtable like I would have expected it to.

How can I convert the string "Filter=*.txt;Path=C:\temp" to a hashtable? I know I can use here strings in general but this is being typed from read host so a single line string is what im trying to convert.

**Possible Answer**

Since `ConvertFrom-StringData`likes new lines I was able to hack this out.

```
PS C:\temp> $hashFromStringData = ("Filter=*.txt;Path=C:\\temp" -Split ";") -Join "`r`n" | ConvertFrom-StringData
$hashFromStringData.GetType().FullName

System.Collections.Hashtable
```

Not sure if there is a better way.

Comment: Got distracted with the Split.. a simple ``-replace ";","`r`n"`` should also work

Comment: Yes, the issue clearly was that `$results` was an array of hash tables, instead of a hash table with multiple key pairs, I think your solution of `-replace ";","\`r\`n"` to better format the input string for `ConvertFrom-StringData` nailed it.

Comment: +1 In Powershell v2, it turns out that an import from a text file also suffered from the same issue. Such that Get-Content myhash.txt|ConvertFrom-StringData also produced an array of text files. Running ``-Join "`r`n"`` on the output of Get-Content allowed this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was close to my own solution but didn't understand the *exact* problem until Micky actually wrote that I had any array of hashtables (seems I was just glazing over the `[]` of `System.Object[]`). Much like Steven Penny quoted `ConvertFrom-StringData` works with a key/value pair on each line.

```
-Split ";" | ConvertFrom-StringData
```

This would have passed several lines creating the array of hashtables. It needed to be one continuous line. The two ways that I was able to address this are:

```
("Filter=*.txt;Path=C:\\temp" -Split ";") -Join "`r`n"
```

or the simpler

```
"Filter=*.txt;Path=C:\\temp".Replace(";","`r`n")
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears this is by design

> The ConvertFrom-StringData cmdlet converts a string that contains one or more
>   key and value pairs into a hash table. Because
>   **each key/value pair must be on a separate line**, here-strings are often
>   used as the input format.

[ConvertFrom-StringData](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849900)