# Powershell Read-Host User Input Addition

Tags: file, powershell

I have a problem and I cannot find a solution online.

I have the following code, and I would like to read two inputs and save them in a text file. When the user puts his email and API token, it creates a text file and separates his input in two lines. I don't know what to use with the `Read-Host`.

For example:

> myname@example.com
>   
>   123456789abcdefg

What I would like to do is to use his input, but have a default name in front of each line such as:

> Email = myname@example.com
>   
>   APIToken = 123456789abcdefg

Here is my code:

```powershell
Write-Host 'Enter your email: '
Read-Host | Out-File $CredsFile

Write-Host 'Enter your API Token: '
Read-Host | Out-File $CredsFile -Append

$CredsFile = $CredsFile -join [Environment]::NewLine
$configuration = ConvertFrom-StringData($CredsFile)
$email = $configuration.'Email'
$api_token = $configuration.'APIToken'
```

Comment: My answer here could help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630925/native-mechanism-for-parsing-input-parameter-value-pairs-from-string/27631598#27631598. It creates a hashtable based on user input from read-host

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place the calls to `Read-Host` inside string literals using [sub-expressions `$(...)`](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html):

```powershell
Write-Host 'Enter your email: '
"Email = $(Read-Host)" | Out-File -Append $CredsFile

Write-Host 'Enter your API Token: '
"APIToken = $(Read-Host)" | Out-File -Append $CredsFile
```

This will allow you build a custom label around each input.

Also, the calls to `Write-Host` are unnecessary since `Read-Host` accepts a prompt string argument:

```powershell
"Email = $(Read-Host 'Enter your email')" | Out-File -Append $CredsFile
"APIToken = $(Read-Host 'Enter your API Token')" | Out-File -Append $CredsFile
```

Finally, make sure you use the `-Append` flag with `Out-File` as I did above.  Without this, the contents of the file will be overwritten with each write operation.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am new with this :-) It worked

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already trying to create a hashtable we *could* use a single `Read-Host` and split the results. Depending on the target audience it could be considered less intuitive but I like opening your options. Especially if you don't need to send the data to file.

```powershell
$input = (Read-Host "Please enter your email and key seperated by a space").Split(" ")
$configuration = @"
    Email = {0}
    APIToken = {1}
"@ -f $input[0],$input[1] | ConvertFrom-StringData

$email = $configuration.Email
$api_token = $configuration.'APIToken'
```

This is assuming that you don't really need to send it to file. You still could. Just does not need to be part of this process.

I saw a comment but I guess you deleted it. If you wanted to output this information to file exactly as you have in your example you could do this.

```powershell
$configuration.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object{"$($_.Name) = $($_.Value)"} | Set-Content $CredsFile
```

Depending on the needs of the files you could make it simpler.